# how to show message if column have equal value

Tags: sql, sql-server

i Have the following table like-

```
column_no     count_no
------------------------
1              2
2              2
3              2
```

if find all count_no value is same i want to return a custom message using strored procedure.

Comment: sql server is not designed to show different messages. You can return some value from stored procedure

Comment: You can `THROW` an error, return one in an `OUTPUT` parameter or `SELECT` a result set that contains the message; take your pick. You can also `PRINT` a message, but this won't be seen by client code calling the procedure (unless they go to the trouble of capturing those messages, which most don't).

Comment: Then start writing a stored procedure - at least a stub - and define what you mean by "sending a message" and what the code that executes your procedure does with this "message". This sounds like you are trying to push logic into the database that more correctly belongs in the application.

Comment: You should use functions for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

declare @msg varchar(500) = 'your custom message'
Create table #temp
(
column_no int ,
count_no int
)

insert into #temp
values 
(1,2),
(2,2),
(3,2)

IF (select count(*) 
    from 
   (select distinct count_no from #temp ) as diff) <> 1 
BEGIN
    select 1 where 1<>1  --select nothing
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    print @msg
END

drop table #temp
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to return if there are any differences, but something like this returns a result set with 0 or one rows:

```
select 'All same'
from t
having min(count_no) = max(count_no);
```

If you want to print the result:

```
if (not exists (select 1 from t having min(count_no) <> max(count_no)))
begin
    print 'All same'
end;
```

Comment: if i want to compare with 1st and 2nd asc order record in a table so its is not correct.

Comment: @doxisoh . . . The question asked is basically:  "if find all count_no value is same i want to return a custom message".  That is what this answer does.  If you have a different question, then ask as a *new* question, provide a clear explanation, sample data, and desired results.